# Dragging to pop view controller causes button pinned to bottom to jump (using a tab bar)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am having an issue with a tab bar controller. See the following image:

[image]

The button is pinned to the safe area bottom. When the view controller is first pushed it appears in the correct place. In `viewWillAppear` I have the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

The view controller that pushes this controller has the following in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

It buttons seems to be jumping because of the tab bar hide/unhide transition. I figured I could just pin it to the bottom of the `view` instead of the safe area, however the button would then not be in the correct place for the iPhoneX. Does anyone have a solution on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

@Sandeep is right, this is one possible solution.
I also experienced this and for me the solution was to change the button bottom constraint, to equal the bottom of superview instead of bottom of layout guide. Layout guide resized after tabbar was hidden and since button's bottom constraint was referenced to it, button jumped. Changing to view solved my issue.